# UISearchbar and UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am developing an application and I have a problem in the UItableview code when I search for one of the cells for example: I want to get into cell 60 and I search it in the search bar it doesn't give me the cell60 it is give me the first cell that is In the table how do I fix it

AllItems is NSArray and displayItems is NSMutableArray

this the code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath



 {


   //Crete an NSSring object that we can use as the eruse identifir
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";



//Check to see if wer can reuse a cell from a row that has just roolerd off the screen

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];



if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

}


cell.textLabel.text = [displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//if there are no cells to be reused creater new cell

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

//set the text attribute to whatever we are currently looking at in our array


//Return the cell
return cell;
}
```

and this the code for searchbar

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
if ([searchText length] == 0) {
    [displayItems removeAllObjects];
    [displayItems addObjectsFromArray:allItems];


} else {

    //here

    [displayItems removeAllObjects];
    for (NSString * string in allItems){
        NSRange r =[string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (r.location != NSNotFound){
            [displayItems addObject:string];
        }
    }
}
[tableView reloadData];


}
```

plese help me

Answer (score 0):

What you should do:

In the header:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* displayItems;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSArray* allItems;
```

In implementation:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    ...
    self.addItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3"];
    self.displayItems = [NSMutableArray array];
}
```

Your methods:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

    if ([searchText length] == 0) {
        [self.displayItems removeAllObjects];
        [self.displayItems addObjectsFromArray:allItems];

    } else {

        [self.displayItems removeAllObjects];
        for (NSString * string in self.allItems ){
        NSRange r =[string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (r.location != NSNotFound){
            [self.displayItems addObject:string];
        }
    }

    [tableView reloadData];

}
```

Table view data source:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.displayItems count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }


    cell.textLabel.text = [self.displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: ok, so you want to filter your cells, you do everything right then, just make sure that your `displayItems ` is retained, better do it as a 'strong' property and use it like `self.displayItems`, also make sure that you return the right number of items in `numberOfRowsInSection` it should be `[self.displayItems count];`.

Comment: and don't forget to allocate `displayItems` somewhere: self.displayItems = [NSMutableArray array];

Comment: You can edit the answer and add your code for this please? Thanks! display itmes is NSMutableArry and ALLItems is NSArray